# Problems with assembly private deployment when the same version is already in the GAC – Report Viewer

Tags: .net, deployment, assemblies, gac

We have a click-once WinForms application that is using the Report Viewer 2010. The assemblies are privately deployed – that is, we do not GAC them (AFAIK, this is the best practice, although I might be wrong).

We are running into the following problem. We require Report Viewer file version 10.0.40219.1 (I believe this is from VS2010 SP1) – it has some bug fixes that the RTM version (10.0.30319.1) does not have. However, one some machines we deploy to, the “bad” (older) assembly is already in the GAC (for example, if the user has installed VS2010 RTM or any other software that decides to GAC the Report Viewer – TFS does that, I believe). Unfortunately, the assembly version of both assemblies is the same, 10.0.0.0. Because of this, the CLR loader ALWAYS picks the GAC assembly over the locally deployed one.

As far as I understand, all Assembly.Load…() methods will load from the GAC first, no matter what, so pre-loading the assembly manually won’t really help us. The only solution I can see is to GAC the ReportViewer assembly we are deploying – but that does not sound like the right thing to do.

Question: what is the proper way for us to ensure the correct Report Viewer assembly gets loaded?

Thanks,

Dave.

Answer (score 0):

Assembly.LoadFile(path) will load the one you want.

EDIT: wrong.

Comment: I don't believe that this is the case. See the community content comment for the MSDN article, for instance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8.aspx:

"Starting in Whidbey beta2, for Assembly.LoadFrom/LoadFile/Load(byte[]), if there is an assembly in GAC with exactly the same assembly identity, we will return the one in GAC."

Comment: I tried a simple test to confirm - 

Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(localPath);
Console.WriteLine(assembly.Location);

The result was pointing into the GAC, not to the location specified in localPath

Comment: Please don't vote this up or down. The only reason I haven't deleted it is so that the rest of the context makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well now you get to play rough. If you have full trust you can hook CreateFileW to open the local copy instead of the one in the GAC; however if it's been ngen'ed that won't work.

You could of course hook the registry functions so scanning the GAC for it doesn't find it.

If the assembly in question is pure managed code, you could run it through ildasm, change the private key, run it through ilasm, sign it, and link to that.

Comment: How do you load an assembly into the CLR using the CreateFile API? These two methods are a bit rough – I am trying to find a reliable workaround to what appears to be a Microsoft bug (not changing the assembly version between RTM and SP1 surely seems to be one). I was hoping for something more obvious – otherwise just GAC’ing my private assembly (mind you, we are talking about the Microsoft Report Viewer redistributable here) seems like a better strategy in the end.

Comment: You don't. I was saying you hook CreateFileW so that the CLR doesn't get the file it asked for.

Comment: Incidentally, I was assuming you had to solve the problem without admin rights.